# Python script execution per user account at set intervals

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, cron

I am working on my dissertation and I am including an AD sync, allowing companies to import their user accounts from their AD server.

I have found Tim Golden's [`active_directory`](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/active_directory.html) Python module which does most of the work for me when it comes to retrieving the user accounts and I am then inserting these into a MongoDB database.

All of this is currently working, but I want to allow each company to set an interval at which the import should run. What would be the best way for me facilitate this? I was thinking of using `cron` to execute the script at intervals but as the potential number of accounts could be large maybe this wouldn't be the best way?

Are there any best practices when it comes to implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this constitutes a best practice or not, but as soon as I started my ".py" file on booting up my machine in `rc.local`, I am doing the  following thing (among others):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
...

def myFunc():
     ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched = BlockingScheduler()
    sched.add_job(myFunc, 'cron', hour="1,6,11,16,21", minute='55')
    sched.start()
```

Comment: So just do that for each and every user account?

Comment: @Sinfieldd  Do it as you wish. You can run your script regularly by cron or put your executable code into `myFunc` and have a cron-like job within script. The result is going to be the same.